# Django admin add related object doesn't open popup window?

Tags: django, django-admin

The django-admin app is supposed to open a popup window when I try to create a related object. For example, clicking the green plus button here:

[image]

Should bring a new pop-up window, where I can create a new related (in this case Session) object. However, when I click the green plus button, the object create opens up in the same window, instead of a pop-up window. This is a problem, because if a user starts to create a primary object, then half-way through, clicks the green plus, he will lose all the progress on the primary object. This means that the green plus is unusable.

I have no idea why this is happening. I understand that I am not providing a minimum example of the problem, because I haven't been able to construct one. Right now I want to **diagnose** the problem. Any ideas of how I can diagnose this? And fix it?

I can provide any information you think is necessary.

Related: [Django admin popup links are broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29811544/855050). But he's using Grappelli, which I am not. I am using the default django admin interface.

I am using Django version 1.8.4.

**UPDATE:** The popups work fine with `manage.py runserver`. The problem only appears with the deployed version under apache. I hope this narrows down the issue.

On google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/awYelJjFjHk.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Popups in my apps stoped working after upgrade to Django 1.8.

Comment: @pista329 I am also using 1.8.

Comment: Are you sure about not using any popup blockers in your browser?

Comment: @ShahulHameed Yes, I am sure popups are not blocked. First thing I checked.

Comment: @pista329 Are you using Grappelli?

Comment: @becko yes, with Grappelli.

Comment: @becko I just tested with Django 1.8.6 and Grappelli 2.7.2. Everything works fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with Django 1.8.2 (without Grappelli) and Firefox 42.0, both on Linux. Just upgraded to Django 1.8.6 after reading this and the problem has gone away.

Comment: @DanDyer I just upgraded with `sudo -E pip install -U Django`. But I'm still getting the same problem. Did you have to do anything else, maybe update something in your project so it uses the newer Django version?

Comment: @becko No, I just changed the version number to 1.8.6 in my requirements.txt and then ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` and restarted the Django dev server. Maybe check that you definitely got 1.8.6 (`pip freeze` should do it)?

Comment: @DanDyer I'm sure I got 1.8.6. I tested with `django.VERSION` in my Python environment, and also by the debug pages generated by my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to produce a minimal example of what was going on, but it is fixed now. Essentially, I did the following:

1. Upgraded to Django 1.8.6 .
2. Ran `python manage.py collectstatic` (as suggested in https://community.webfaction.com/questions/18544/there-is-not-popup-window-for-one-to-many-relationship-with-djangos-admin-v18)

So in the end I'm not sure what the issue was. I hope this is useful to someone else.

If someone else comes up with a more complete answer, which involves a minimal example and with an explanation of what was going on, I'll be glad to change the accepter answer.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a reproducible error in 1.9.3. Testing it myself I setup a new project using the latest Django (1.9.3) and ran into the same error.  Below is the fix.  It seems to also work with 1.9.1  I will report to Django team now.

```
+++ b/contrib/admin/templates/admin/related_widget_wrapper.html
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
         </a>
         {% endif %}
         {% if can_add_related %}
-        <a class="related-widget-wrapper-link add-related" id="add_id_{{ name }}"
+        <a class="related-widget-wrapper-link add-another" id="add_id_{{ name }}"
             href="{{ add_related_url }}?{{ url_params }}"
             title="{% blocktrans %}Add another {{ model }}{% endblocktrans %}">
             <img src="{% static 'admin/img/icon-addlink.svg' %}" alt="{% trans 'Add' %}"/>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11499853)

Comment: This is not a new question.  This is a solution based on a 'minimal example' and an 'explanation of what was going on' as requested by @becko

Comment: Thanks @discostu  I've edited your answer to make it a little clearer that you are giving an answer and not just saying "I have that too" or asking a different question.