# Can not edit foreign key field in Django admin and pop-up form is not really popping up

Tags: django-admin, django-suit

I am using Django-suit for admin panel. My 'user' model has 'address' and 'contact' fields as foreign key. When trying to change the user's info, the address and contact fields has **change/edit** and **add new** options beside them. But the **change/edit** option remains disabled ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtWdG.png)).

Besides, when I click on **add new** icon, a new form window is supposed to pop-up. But instead it take me to the form in same browser tab. Any insight for solving this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: Without having any solution of the specified problem, I tried to bypass that by showing foreign key fields as 'tabularinline'. So, that user can edit foreignkey fields directly (no edit button required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting question from @Efi MK, I tried once again to dig into the problem, and found my mistake with the help from this post ([Django admin add related object doesn't open popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189728/django-admin-add-related-object-doesnt-open-popup-window)).

The main project was previously implemented using Django-1.6. I was extending the project by adding some new features using Django-1.11. The problem is, the static files I was using for Django-admin, were from previous version. The 'collectstatic' command didn't replace those files from previous version which has same name as new version. Unfortunately, I didn't notice that.

I deleted whole 'static' folder, ran 'collectstatic' again, and both of the problems mentioned in the question were solved. Thanks, Efi for asking :)